# Unity Torrents lens not working

Tags: unity, lenses, bittorrent

The Unity torrents lens is not working for me.
If I select it and search for, say, `ubuntu`, I do not get any results.

Is it not working in general (since pirate bay is down or something) or is this a problem of my computer?

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)